# What is the difference between canonical forms?

Tags: linear-algebra

what is the difference between jordan canonical form and quadratic form canonical form?
I really do not understand the difference- why there is two canonial forms?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a particular mathematical context there may be an accepted format for describing an object. That way may be called the "canonical form". Usually it's established as a convention, not a formal rule.

In your examples you are talking about two different kinds of objects: linear operators and quadratic forms. Each has it's own "canonical form". They have nothing to do with each other.

The  canonical form you refer to for linear operators has the adjective "Jordan" because it's one of many standard ways to write a matrix for an operator. Another "canonical form" is the matrix with respect to the usual (canonical) coordinate system (when that is relevant).

Comment: thank you for the fast answer, now I start to understand the concept